# Swift UITableviewcell Checkmark on and off and when on to write a numeric value to a total

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I've been spending the last week and a half on this but i can't figure it out

I'm creating an app that has multiple cells in a table view, those cells are part of a section *there is 5 section*

when a cell is press a checkmark has to appear a the right of the cell
when it is pressed again the checkmark goes away

when a checkmark is present it has a numeric value, this value is written on a label a the bottom of the page (if multiple checkmarks they add up and you see the total at the bottom)

a reset button unchecks all cells to bring the score back to zero

NOW

I'm unable to populate the cells, much less able to created sections, I've been able to do it using static cells, but it does not work inside a ViewController

I'm unable to select the cells to have a checkmark (I select accessory view but nothing else happen)

can't link the cells to the reset button (i've been able to make it workishhhh using a UISwitch but only if the switch is out of the table view, which did not help me at all)

I'm using swift

I thank you all very much if you can help me in this, I seriously exhausted all resources i have and I don't have anyone else to turn to

Sincerely, a desperate Jp4Real

UPdate

I've modified the code now i have populated the rows, I need to separated them in sections

I have multiple array of data, 5 sections to be precise

Code

```
import UIKit
```

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

```
let section1 =
   ["this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",]
let section2 =
   ["this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",
    "this is used tot test the lenght of the text",]

@IBOutlet weak var scoreshow: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var reset: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return self.section1.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
    cell.textLabel!.text = section1[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 3

    return cell
}


@IBAction func resetswitch(sender: UIButton) {
 }
```

}

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to solve all your problems at once.  Start at the beginning...how are you trying to populate your cells?  Do you have a datasource?  If so, what do its methods look like?

Comment: I've added the datasource

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with cells.  How are you using `stuff`?

Comment: modified added my view controller.swift code

Comment: Stuff is just the label of the cell, it will be a question and if the answer is yes the user presses it and the checkmark appears

Comment: If you get rid of the image-related code there, do you get your cells displayed?

Comment: crashes here :   <br/>         var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = stuff[indexPath.row]   <br/>

Comment: I think you're right i'm trying to do it all at the same time @PhillipMills; i've listed my stuff and i first need to populate the cells as you said. can you help me do that ? I've tried multiple ways online but I can't get a hold of it

Comment: I've modified the code, i've been able to populate the cells, now i need to create sections from multiple array of data, 5 to be precise

Comment: Create an array of arrays ([section1, section2, ...]) called `allSections`.  Then use the section number you are given in the method calls to choose the right array.  E.g.: `return self.allSections[section].count`.

Comment: im gettin an error : Viewcontroller.Type does not have a member named section1.....                    I have multiple arrays because i want to split them in sections (with headers) maybe it's easier to do it all from 1 array?